# Can you publish only obstacles from a costmap

Tags: navigation, occupancy-grid, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering if it is possible to publish only the cells (points) that are occupied in a given costmap_2d object using the newer layered costmap approach in Hydro? This was how the nav_msgs/GridCells worked on the /obstacles topic of old and it was a useful feature.

I suppose it would not be terribly difficult to write a node that subscribes to the /costmap topic now and converts the occupancy grid into a GridCells message of occupied cells, but I'm just curious if that functionality is built in to the current implementation of costmap_2d or not. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119096/can-you-publish-only-obstacles-from-a-costmap/) by [Matt_Derry](https://answers.ros.org/users/3061/matt_derry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-01-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not currently built in. You are correct that you could write another node, since the information for the gridcells is a subset of the information in the costmap.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1